# String parser function does not correctly write to the tuple

Tags: c++, parsing, tuples

Context

My program takes in functions that can either be made up of a **string** or a **string and an integer** i.e.

*"transition 1440"*

*"journey"*

I am trying to write a string parser to read these commands line by line and feed them through a parser that I created. This function is meant to output a tuple(string, int) where the integer part is set to -1 by default if there is one word in the command (makes it easier to process down the line).

The problem that I have is that while the first word is always assigned correctly, the integer part is never found. I abstracted the issue to the part in my code that is giving me issues. Any help would be much appreciated.

## Operator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <istream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>


//operator
bool space(char c) {
    return isspace(c);
}
```

## Function

```
std::tuple<std::string, int> split(std::string s)
{
    std::tuple<std::string, int> v;
    auto start = std::find_if_not(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), space);
    int count = 0;
    std::get<1>(v) = -1;

    while (start != s.cend()) {
        auto end = find_if(start, s.cend(), space);

        if (count == 0)
        {
            std::get<0>(v) = (std::string(start, end));
            ++count;
        }
        else if (count == 1)
        {
            // Secondary word is assumed to be an integer
            std::get<1>(v) = stoi(std::string(start, end));
        }

        start = find_if_not(end, s.cend(), space);
    }
    std::cout << std::get<0>(v) << '\t' << std::get<1>(v);

    return v;
}
```

## Main

```
int main()
{
    std::tuple<std::string, int> x = split("move");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you wrap isspace inside space?

Comment: Using `auto start = std::find_if_not(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), isspace(c));` does not work and having to use a lambda expression everytime I use a find_if or find_if_not will create the issue of code duplication.

Comment: Seems to [work for me](https://godbolt.org/z/WWP4v7)

Comment: @BaileyKocin: `isspace` has overloads (from [locale](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isspace), and from [ctype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace)).